# Find the Second Max in a list of values using linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

How can I find the second maximum number in a list of values using `Linq` and `C#`?

For example I have this list:

```
List<double> ListOfNums = new List<double> {1, 5, 7, -1, 4, 8};
```

Is there a method I can get the second maximum value in the list which is 7?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var secondMax = ListOfNums.OrderByDescending(r => r).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

OR

```
var secondMax = ListOfNums.OrderByDescending(r=> r).Take(2).LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: would there be exception if list contains a single item ?

Comment: no it will return zero in  this case as is the default value for int

Comment: @NewHire, No, it would return the default value `0.0`.

Comment: I know and I did. SO wouldn't let me at the time. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Habib Good answer

Answer (score 2):

just convert it to an  array and take the second element

```
 List<double> ListOfNums = new List<double> { 1, 5, 7, -1, 4, 8 };
 var  sndmax = ListOfNums.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray()[1];
```

Comment: possible case of index out of range exception if list contains a single item

Comment: Sure  he should check against this

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `List<T>.Sort` method:

```
ListOfNums.Sort();
var max = ListOfNums[1];
```

Comment: possible case of index out of range exception if list contains a single item

Answer (score 0):

For a bit more complicated objects a solution like below could be used. I post just for someone may need have an idea.
For example we want to  find the 3. Maximum grade point achieved by the students from the list of students.

This is the basic class for create a sample list for us :

```
 public class Students
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int GradePoint { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public List<Students> GetStudentRecords()
    {
        List<Students> stulist = new List<Students>();
        stulist.Add(new Students { StudentId = 1, StudentName = " Joseph ", GradePoint = 800 });
        stulist.Add(new Students { StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Alex", GradePoint = 458 });
        stulist.Add(new Students { StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Harris", GradePoint = 900 });
        stulist.Add(new Students { StudentId = 4, StudentName = "Taylor", GradePoint = 900 });
        stulist.Add(new Students { StudentId = 5, StudentName = "Smith", GradePoint = 458 });
        stulist.Add(new Students { StudentId = 6, StudentName = "Natasa", GradePoint = 700 });
        stulist.Add(new Students { StudentId = 7, StudentName = "David", GradePoint = 750 });
        stulist.Add(new Students { StudentId = 8, StudentName = "Harry", GradePoint = 700 });
        stulist.Add(new Students { StudentId = 9, StudentName = "Nicolash", GradePoint = 597 });
        stulist.Add(new Students { StudentId = 10, StudentName = "Jenny", GradePoint = 750 });
        return stulist;
    }
}
```

We call our list and write the output:

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var students = new Students();
        students.GetStudentRecords()
           .GroupBy(grp => grp.GradePoint)
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).Skip(2)
           .Take(1)
           .SelectMany(s => s)
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(p => 
           Console.WriteLine($"Id : {p.StudentId}, Name : {p.StudentName}, achieved Grade Point : {p.GradePoint} "));
    }
  }
```

And this is the output :

> Id : 7, Name : David, achieved Grade Point : 750
>
> Id : 10, Name : Jenny, achieved Grade Point : 750