# Get third highest date from the collection

Tags: c#

I have a array of DateTime object , I want to get the third highest date from it.

```
DateTime[] dateTimes = new DateTime[]
            {
                new DateTime(2001, 04, 14),
                new DateTime(2061, 12, 29),
                new DateTime(2019, 10, 21),
                new DateTime(1973, 01, 07),
                new DateTime(2014, 07, 19),
                new DateTime(1992, 03, 11),
                new DateTime(2019, 10, 21)
            };


            var third = dateTimes.Select(d => new
            {
                d.Year,
                d.Month,
                FormattedDate = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day)
            })
            .Distinct()
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.Year)
            .ThenByDescending(d => d.Month)
            .Skip(2)
            .Select(d => d.FormattedDate);
```

this is returning a collection , the result should be 19-07-2014

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the Second Max in a list of values using linq c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872592/find-the-second-max-in-a-list-of-values-using-linq-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` after `Skip` returns the rest of the collection. You need `FirstOrDefault` at the end:

```
var third = dateTimes.Select(d => new
{
    d.Year,
    d.Month,
    FormattedDate = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day)
})
.Distinct()
.OrderByDescending(d => d.Year)
.ThenByDescending(d => d.Month)
.Skip(2)
.Select(d => d.FormattedDate)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

After that you need to check the result for the default value, which will be returned if the original sequence has fewer than three distinct elements.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're comparing just year and month? This should work fine:

```
var third = dateTimes.Distinct().OrderByDescending(d => d).Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();
```

There's also no need to create a new `DateTime` based on your example array. However, if you want to strip the time of day, you can add `Select(d => d.Date)` to the mix:

```
var third = dateTimes.Select(d => d.Date).Distinct().OrderByDescending(d => d).Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: If the hours of the day are different, then distinct will not differentiate between the two. Otherwise this is essentially the same thing I would suggest as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is some convolution here. There is no need to project into a separate object that isn't being used. Simply use the formatted date in your projection.

```
var third = dateTimes.Select(d => new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day))
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(d => d)
    .Skip(2)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will give you **7/19/2014**